# How do I show $y=\ \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2^{x}+1\ }$ is odd?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, even-and-odd-functions

Of course I know that $f(-x)=-f(x)$, but I get confused as to how $$\frac{1}{2}-\frac{2^{x}}{2^{x}+1\ }=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{1+2^{x}}$$ In the steps of algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from where you left off:

$$\frac12 - \frac{2^x}{2^x+1} = \frac12-\left(\frac{2^x+1}{2^x+1}-\frac1{2^x+1}\right) = \frac12-1+\frac1{2^x+1}$$

Comment: ahh, I see. I see this trick alllll the time yet I wasn't able to figure that out for this question :((

Answer (score 6):

So, I'd recommend turning the function into a proper fraction, so we get
$$ f(x) =  \dfrac{2^x-1}{2^{x+1}+2} $$

Therefore, $f(-x)$ is equal to
$$ f(-x) = \dfrac{2^{-x}-1}{2^{-x+1}+2}$$

Multiply by $\dfrac{2^x}{2^x}$ and we get
$$ f(-x) = \dfrac{1-2^x}{2^1+2\cdot 2^x} = \dfrac{1-2^x}{2^{x+1}+2} = -f(x)$$

Like we wanted.

Comment: Damnit, I did try this method but my algebra is too weak then

Comment: Actually, I got close but I wouldn't have thought of multiplying by $\frac{2^x}{2^x}$

Comment: Its just trial and error until you get your algebraic technique right. Glad I could help! :)

Comment: What would you mean by trial and error?

Comment: When I was a beginner, I also didn't notice a lot of tricks that I notice today. It's just a lot of practice until you get your technique right.

Comment: How would you get the final expression back into 2 fractions though?

Comment: You could subtract $2$ from the denominator (and add again) and get $\dfrac{1-2^x -2 + 2}{2(2^x +1)} = \dfrac{(-1-2^x) + 2}{2(2^x+1)}$. Cancel stuff out and you'll get $-\dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{1}{2^x+1}$

Comment: Again I would have not thought of this. However, I tried using partial fractions (didn't work but its probably just me). Do partial fractions work in this case?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115857/discussion-between-talbi-and-user71207).

Answer (score 0):

There's really no trick:

$\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2^{-x}+1\ }= \frac{1}{2^{x}+1\ }- \frac{1}{2} \Longleftrightarrow$

$1 = \frac{1}{2^{-x}+1\ }+ \frac{1}{2^{x}+1\ }$ and multiplying by the product of the denominators  we get $\Longleftrightarrow$

$1= \frac{2^{x}+1 + 2^{-x}+1}{(2^{x}+1)(2^{-x}+1)}=\frac{2^{x}+1 + 2^{-x}+1}{2^{x}+1 + 2^{-x}+1}$. Since these steps are reversible the initial equality is true.